# NFS unable to mount server denied Access

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, nfs, aix

On the server side (AIX)

```
vi /etc/exports
/NFS -rw
exportfs -a
```

On the client side, which is my laptop with ubuntu os.

```
showmount -e 192.168.119.56
Export list for 192.168.119.56:
/NFS (everyone)
```

While mounting to shared files directory it shows following error:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -vvvv -o nfsvers=3 192.168.119.56:/NFS /home/lastvirus/sharedfiles
mount.nfs: timeout set for Wed Jun 21 16:52:08 2023
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'nfsvers=3,addr=192.168.119.56'
mount.nfs: prog 100003, trying vers=3, prot=6
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.119.56 prog 100003 vers 3 prot TCP port 2049
mount.nfs: prog 100005, trying vers=3, prot=17
mount.nfs: trying 192.168.119.56 prog 100005 vers 3 prot UDP port 57183
mount.nfs: mount(2): Permission denied
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.119.56:/NFS
```

This might be helpful for nfs version.

```
rpcinfo 192.168.119.56 |egrep "service|nfs"
   program version netid     address                service    owner
    100003    2    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    2    udp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        unknown
    100003    3    udp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    3    udp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        unknown
    100003    2    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    2    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        unknown
    100003    3    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    3    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        unknown
    100003    4    tcp       0.0.0.0.8.1            nfs        unknown
    100003    4    tcp6      ::.8.1                 nfs        unknown
```

Comment: It's a timeout. Check network connectivity. Check for any firewalls.

Comment: @paladin network connectivity is good. do i need to check ufw on client machine:?

Comment: You should check the firewall on the server. I recommend enabling logging of all DROP's to see if you are blocking a port you didn't intend to, and ensure those are open to the relevant IP ranges.

Comment: @Mikael How can i ? i m new to AIX.